# Is it possible to do a group by case in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, group-by, google-bigquery

It's supposed that I have a table with a key and some other columns. The key column has the next shape (all Strings):

key1:  '2','1','3','1','1','2',' ', '4',' ', '4','1','k',' ','k'

And I would like to group by key1 in order to sum another values. I only want to group the numeric keys, I mean, I don't want to group keys like 'k', ' ', ... Because I don't want to sum these values.

Is there any way to do a group by in case that the key would be a numeric key? or to put any regex or similar?

Comment: what did you tried?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please edit your question to show a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You can also read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you want?

```
select (case when regexp_contains(key, '^[0-9]+$')
             then 'numbers'
             else key
        end) as newkey,
       count(*)
from t
group by newkey;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon Linoff! That's not exactly what I'm looking for. Imagine we have a column that is the primary key (fruits). And in that column there are register with: Strawberry, apple, orange... and there are registers that are wrong and have things like "asdf", "    ", "potato". i want to group all the apples, all the oranges and all the strawberries, but I dont want to group the rest of values. If there are three registers with "potato", I dont want to group them. Do you think if it is possible?

Comment: @jonaetn . . . I don't see how our comment changes the gist of this answer.  You've introduced strings instead of numbers, but the idea is the same.  Perhaps you should write a *new* question and provide sample data, desired results, and a better explanation of what you want to accomplish.